# how to save my unput's text in the same form

Tags: php

I have a form with some `input text`. I want to save the `text` of all my inputs but I don't know how to do it...
I tried the following:

```php
$varEmp = myForm.MyTextbox.text;
```

But it doesn't work...

**I dont want to send my data to an other form**, just save it to use it later, I don't want to send it to an other php file

I have:

```php
<form name="f1"  method="post" id="contact-form" class="smart-form">
    ....
    <input type="text" name="empresa" id="empresa" " value="" />
    ...
</form> 

// code and more code

<?php
    function actil()
    {       
        $nomempresa = f1.empresa.gettext();
    }
?>
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Hm, that doesn't look like php. You can use `$nomempresa = $_POST['name_of_form'];` to get the content of an input field.

Comment: @Kommodore: does it work even when i'm not sending my form to other php file?

Comment: Yeah, it should work [Link to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: you notice that you defined your function but didn't call it?

Comment: I call it in a button.. @IdanMagled ´<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="actil()">Actualizar</button>´

Comment: @Jean well, you cannot do it like that, I'll show you how to do that in an answer

Comment: You cant call a function in php from js.

i suggest that you delete this question and google for a bit.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form name="f1"  method="post" id="contact-form" class="smart-form">
....
<input type="text" name="empresa" id="empresa" " value="" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="actil">Actualizar</button>
...
```

```
<?php
    if("POST"==$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
    {
        if(isset($_POST['actil'] AND isset($_POST['empresa']))
        {       
            $nomempresa = $_POST['empresa'];
        }
    }
?>
```

This should work in your case. With `if("POST"==$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])` I check if *a* submit button was actually used, after that I check if *the* exact button was used and if the field isn't empty. Then I just put the content of the input field in the variable `$nomempresa`.
Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy form data preservation:

```
<?php
    $input = array();

    function printValue($input,$field,$default = null) {
        echo (array_key_exists($field,$input))
            ? $input[$field]
            : $default;
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        $input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
    #   manipulate data here
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Form Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>" method="post">
            <h1>Form Test</h1>
            <dl>
                <dt>
                    <label for="foo">Foo</label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" value="<?php printValue($input,'foo'); ?>"/>
                </dd>
                <dt>
                    <label for="bar">Bar</label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <input type="text" name="bar" id="bar" value="<?php printValue($input,'bar'); ?>"/>
                </dd>
            </dl>
            <p>
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Analysis:

- Creating `$input` at the beginning just reserves it.
- The function `printValue()` checks if a field exists in input. If it exist, it prints it. If it doesn't it prints the default value. The default value is optional.
- The request method checks how you're interacting with it (look up [request methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)).
- The function [`filter_input_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) gets all input values of a particular type. Look up the other things you can do with it, and see what things you can do to validate and handle the input.
- The function [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) strips out path information and `__FILE__` is a constant value containing the file name. A formality in case a browser doesn't do anything because there's no `action` value.
- For a field to show up as input, it must use the `name` attribute. So, `<input name="test"/>` will, in this example, show up as `$input['test']`. You can also submit data as arrays, but you need to get comfortable with PHP first.